# boolean issue on copy to SD, need some help to correct

Tags: java, android, boolean, contextmenu

With a lot of help (on here) I've managed to nearly get my app up and running but I've got a problem. I'm basically a beginner in Java so this is a little deep for me, but I would still like some help. Basically the app displays a list of tones and lets you play them, if you touch and hold it inflates a context menu with an option to copy that selected tone to SD card. 
The issue I know lies on the fourth-to-last line:

```
boolean saved = saveas(sound.getSoundResourceId(),"filename");
```

because the variable

```
saved
```

is not used.
I'm not too sure how to fix this,or what i should put in place of `saved`, just wondering if anyone on here has a clue?
Here's the full code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.selector);
//create a simple list
mSounds = new ArrayList<Sound>();
Sound s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Affirmative");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.affirmative);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Anjels");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.anjels);
mSounds.add(s);
s = new Sound();
s.setDescription("Aggro");
s.setSoundResourceId(R.raw.aggro);
mSounds.add(s);
mSounds.add(s);
mAdapter = new SoundAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
mp.start();

}@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  }

public boolean saveas(int ressound, String fName){  
    byte[] buffer=null;  
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);  
    int size=0;  

    try {  
     size = fIn.available();  
     buffer = new byte[size];  
     fIn.read(buffer);  
     fIn.close();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
     return false;  
    }  

    String path="notifications/halon/"; 
    String filename=fName+".ogg";
    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String completePath = baseDir + File.separator + "music" + File.separator + "halon" + File.separator + filename;


    boolean exists = (new File(completePath)).exists();  
    if (!exists){new File(completePath).mkdirs();}  

    FileOutputStream save;  
    try {  
     save = new FileOutputStream(completePath);  
     save.write(buffer);  
     save.flush();  
     save.close();  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
     return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {  
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
     return false;  
    }      

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

    File k = new File(path, filename);  

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "exampletitle");  
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

    //Insert it into the database  
    this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);  

    return true;  
   }
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Sound sound = (Sound) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
    int length = mSounds.size(); // get the length of mSounds object
    String[] names = new String[length]; // creates a fixed array with strings
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         // add sound name to string array
         names[i] = mSounds.get(i).getDescription(); // returns the string name
    }
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.copytosd:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Applying " + getResources().getString(R.string.copy) +
                      " for " + names[(int)info.id],
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          boolean saved = saveas(sound.getSoundResourceId(),"filename");
          return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}}
```

Comment: It is unclear what kind of issue do you have

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use `saved`, delete the `boolean saved =` from that statement and just have `saveas(sound.getSoundResourceId(),"filename");`.

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the error, but still not copying to the SD card. just wondering whether I've got my paths in order as I know it's not good to hard-code paths in the source. Can you see any other problems or anything I might have missed?

Comment: @SeanBurrage: Well, your `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` appears to be wrong. Hold onto `new File(completePath)` (rather than creating it multiple times), then use `Uri.fromFile(completePath)` for your `Intent`.

Comment: Would there be chance of you posting an in-line edit of the code? You seem to be the only person on here that will help.

Comment: @SeanBurrage: To be blunt, if you cannot implement what I described, you need to step away from Android development for a while and learn Java. Trying to learn Java and Android at the same time is likely to frustrate you and others. That being said, replace `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));` with `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(completePath)));` (not exactly what I suggested, but it should fix the problem).

Comment: No no sorry, I missed out a word, it's just every time I tried what you suggested is was pulling up an error, but it's fine now. Thanks